# Proxy server authentication for WCF service

Tags: wcf, proxy

I need to consume a WCF service but I'm behind a proxy server and this proxy server requires a username and password.

I can't find a way to set it, if it was a Web Service, I could just do something like

```
ws.Proxy = myProxyServer;
```

How can I do this with a WCF service?

Comment: Having the answer accepted would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In the WCF binding config, use the useDefaultWebProxy property to make WCF use the windows default proxy (which can be set from IE network config):

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="ESBWSSL" ...everything...  useDefaultWebProxy="true">
```

Then in the code, before you use the connection, do this:

```
WebProxy wproxy = new WebProxy("new proxy",true);
wproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
```

and with your webrequest object, before you execute the call:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = wproxy;
```

I have not tested the code, but I believe this should work.

Comment: what about the username and password?

Comment: Hi Hans, I just added extra info. Can you try that? I have not used it, but it should work.

Comment: @Eduardo: he's using WCF. Are you certain that WCF uses the WebRequest.DefaultProxy property?

Comment: @John - actually - yes! I was surprised myself, too - but check out this link here:   http://blogs.msdn.com/stcheng/archive/2008/12/03/wcf-how-to-supply-dedicated-credentials-for-webproxy-authentication.aspx

Comment: I actually had a problem with it the other day and that's how I found about it. The option was enabled in the app.config, but no proxy was configured. Somebody then decided to access the web on the performance test server and set up proxy, which made everything stop working..

Comment: Actually you need to set useDefaultWebProxy="false" to use the proxy that you configure

Comment: Thank you, thank you thank you. Is there anything more vile than a network proxy server? Solution above worked perfectly.

Comment: Great to know it helped, Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** replaced previous answer based on comment

There was actually another stackoverflow answer that covered setting credentials on a proxy.

[Is it possible to specify proxy credentials in your web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config)

Comment: I think he wants to be able to set authentication for the proxy server. Also, it might help to show how the code would set them: where did "client" come from in your example, for instance?