# Communicating with WCF service via Web Proxy; from within a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, proxy

I am trying to communicate between a Windows Service on several PCs, and a WCF service hosted on my web server (different network).

When there is no proxy between the client and server, communication works fine.

However, when there is a proxy in place between client and server, I cannot figure out how to authenticate against it.

In the old .asmx days, I did something like this:

```
myService.Proxy = new WebProxy("internal.proxyserver.com", 8080)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword" , "mydomain");
};
```

I couldn't find an equivalent way to do this in WCF.

I have tried changing the DefaultWebProxy of the WebRequest object, and assigning credentials that way, but this doesn't seem to work, and I am unable to connect to the web service.

ASMX made this very easy; can somebody explain the correct procedure for this in WCF?

**EDIT:** The relevance of mentioning that this is in a Windows Service is that the client runs without a user supplying credentials, they need to be hard coded/config filed into the application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify proxy credentials in your web.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following links should help you sort out the issue:

[**[WCF]How to supply dedicated credentials for webproxy authentication in WCF client**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stcheng/archive/2008/12/03/wcf-how-to-supply-dedicated-credentials-for-webproxy-authentication.aspx)

[**How to use HTTP proxy authentication in WCF**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5f8d2c3a-164f-411a-b387-91f0be51f190/how-to-use-http-proxy-authentication-in-wcf?forum=wcf)

[Proxy server authentication for WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022692/proxy-server-authentication-for-wcf-service)

Comment: Bingo, a combination of those two were perfect!