# Use svcutil.exe with a webproxy

Tags: .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

I have a scenario where I need to consume a service using svcutil.exe but the wsdl of the service contains the following sections

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://mysite/service.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://mysite/service.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://mysite/service.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Pensjonskalkulator"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://mysite/service.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Problem is that these schema locations are only accessible through a webproxy. If I setup the proxy in IE settings I can browse the schema locations in IE. But it looks like svcutil.exe ignores these settings when downloading these extra schemas.

How do I get svcutil.exe to use my webproxy when downloading extra information?

UPDATE: Actually, the proxy settings entered in Internet Explorer works on svcutil.exe. It was other unrelated issues that caused my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to specify a proxy for svcutil.exe to use by setting it up in Internet Explorer -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Proxy Server and then specify address and port.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to svcutil.config

```
<system.net>   
  <defaultProxy>     
     <proxy proxyaddress="http://your.proxy.com:8080"  bypassonlocal="true" /> 
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

If your proxy requires authentication refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/194414/578411) to provide a username/password and/or domain.

Comment: That didn't seem to have any effect on it, good suggestion though.

Comment: Can you give some guidance on how to handle authentication on the proxy server please? I'm hoping to avoid the 'surprise'.

Comment: @Badgerspot added a link