# reCaptcha validation with timeout exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, captcha, recaptcha

I am using reCaptch in my MVC 3 web app running in the localhost.

Things were working fine few weeks back but suddenly failing.

Suddenly getting this error.

```
if(!ReCaptcha.Validate(_config.RecaptchaPrivateKey)){ <-- times out here
  //process other fields in the form
}
```

As soon as I fill the form and hot submit I get this **error :**

> The operation has timed out

**Description :** *An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current* ...

**Exception Details :** *System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out*

Is this a proxy issue?
Is this because my site on localhost runs on port 3316?

```
localhost:3316/user/signup
```

I saw some posts that suggests that reCAPTCHA expects port 80 but my app runs on port 3316

What can be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by creating proxy class that inherits IWebProxy.

Then specifying to use this proxy when internal, I had to transform it out for other environments that didn't need to use it.

See this question and accepted answer:

[Is it possible to specify proxy credentials in your web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config)

The above link took some finding, so I favourited it for future use.

Comment: How do I find what proxy address to use? Also what username and password to use?

Comment: Hi, the proxy address & network details are for your local network. :)

Comment: reCaptcha fails when I am not in any network. Just my PC connected to internet.