# Access SmartSheet API behind corporate firewall .Net C#

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

I have just started a development to update a smart sheet document using the API.

Using the example (csharp-read-write-sheet) in the SDK reference I can update the the document as long as I am on an open internet connection, however, I cannot when I am connected to the company LAN as it is reporting a proxy authentication issue.

This is the code from the SDK

```
string accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessToken"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
    accessToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
    throw new Exception("Must set API access token in App.conf file");

// Get sheet Id from App.config file 
string sheetIdString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SheetId"];
long sheetId = long.Parse(sheetIdString);

// Initialize client
SmartsheetClient ss = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(accessToken).Build();

// Load the entire sheet
Sheet sheet = ss.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null,     null, null, null);
Console.WriteLine("Loaded " + sheet.Rows.Count + " rows from sheet: " + sheet.Name);
```

Can you please advise how I can configure the API to provide a `System.Net.WebProxy` object to the Client API to provide authentication route through the company proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steve Weil's answer does not allow for you to provide user credentials.... Further research based on it though ended me up at [Is it possible to specify proxy credentials in your web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config) which has now solved my issues

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the SDK doesn't expose the underlying WebRequest object. 
However you can specify proxy information in your `app.config` file.

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy>
            <proxy proxyaddress="http://my-actual-proxy-url" />
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

See related question: [C# Connecting Through Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy)

Comment: OK Thanks ... But could you please add this as a feature for the next release cycle.

Comment: Only problem is that this does not allow for credentials to be provided (see my own answer below)

Comment: Yes, added to our backlog