# Getting response on GET Request C#

Tags: c#, api, http, get, webclient

I'm trying the following code to execute a GET request using C#.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            string url = the url;
            wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token");
            var json = wc.DownloadData(url);
            Console.Write(json);   
        }
```

However, I always get timeout expired exception.  I tried the same get request on *https://www.hurl.it/* and was successfully able to get response.  Am I missing something. I'm using all the parameters in the url.

Comment: Maybe a proxy problem? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config

Comment: Can you share the exception?

Comment: Have you tried your request in something like Postman to make sure that it works?

Comment: I have tried it in postman and it works just fine. @Gareth

Comment: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time @Ygalbel

Comment: I tried the solutions by adding 
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
But it is throwing the same exception @Nuz

Comment: Try with Fiddler to check the difference between **Hurl** and your request